# Let's Encrypt の認証失敗 (Apache2.4)

Tags: linux, apache, raspbian, letsencrypt

タイトルの通り証明書を取得しようとした場合にエラーになります。

ググってもnginxのものばかりで設定の変更方法がわからないため質問しました。
以下がエラーメッセージです。
なお、ドメイン名の部分は質問中では仮に`example.com`で置き換えてあります。

実際のドメインはFreenomで取得、DDNSはMyDNSで設定しました。

**実行したコマンド**

```
% certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html/ -d example.com
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: exapmle.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/BPfelWj7Xw6JFQgBuUN3cBStoTI0mPNU4yJe6hAJhjA
[XXX.XX.XX.XX]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01
   Frameset//EN\"
   \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd\">\n\n<html>\n  <head>\n
   <titl"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Comment: エラーメッセージだけでなく、証明書を取得しようとした時に行った手順(=実行したコマンド)等の情報もあると回答が付きやすいと思います。質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: 例えば仮のテストページを置くなどして、取得したドメインでWebサーバ(Apache)にアクセスできることは確認済みですか？

Comment: 確認していないです、、、

Comment: 取得したドメインで、ウェブサーバにアクセスするにはどうしたらいいですか？

Comment: Apacheとネットワークの全くの初心者ですみません汗

Comment: 証明書を取得する際、指定したドメインが存在するかを実際に外部(Let's Encrypt側)からアクセスして確かめる手順でエラーになっているように見えます。 / Apacheでのドメイン設定等が分からないのであれば、別質問として投稿してみてください。

Comment: なるほど、調べると確かにそのようなことが出てくるのですが、大抵のユーザーがnginxでして、Apacheの場合の設定変更について書かれているページが中々見当たらないんですよね汗。

Comment: とりあえずApacheの設定については自身で調べてみて、server name を取得したドメインに設定してそのページにアクセスできるか確認してみます！

Comment: 調べましたところAppachの  ServerNameの値を取得したドメイン名に設定したところ、ドメイン名でApacheサーバーにアクセスすることはできませんでした。しかし、IPアドレスでならApacheサーバーにアクセスできました。これは名前解決がうまく言っていないということでしょうか？

Comment: 残念ながらStackOverFlowではコメントで質問は推奨されません。一投稿に付き一問一答が基本です。新たな質問のようですので、新しく投稿をしてください